# How to locate the Android ViewGroup element?

Tags: java, android, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

There is a calendar layout hierarchy. I'd like to locate each element in the ViewGroup. I can achieve it by hardcoding the Whole XPath, apparently it's quite un-efficient. Is there any better approach to do this?

Screenshot and the Hierarchy are given blow:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a simple way myself:

```
Grid.androidDriver().findElementByXPath("//*[@resource-id='com.{path}:id/header_layout']/following::android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/descendant::android.widget.FrameLayout[@enabled='true']/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'"+date+"')]").click();
```